# how to read and manipulate a dictionary and file python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have a file that looks like so:
{"Apples": 14, "Bananas": 14, "Pineapples": 0, "Pears": 8}

im trying to figure out how i can read this file in and be able to use it so that i can for example reduce the "apples" value to lower i.e 13 from 14

Comment: That looks like JSON, so you should use the `json` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming its just a text file:

You can just read the file and create a dictionary using `literal_eval()`

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open("file.txt") as f:
    a = f.read()
    dic= literal_eval(a)
```

At this point you can just modify anything in the dict:

```
dic["apples"] = 13
```

To write it back to file you can just convert it back to a string and write:

```
w = str(dic)

with open("file.txt", "w+") as f:
    f.write(w)
```

Comment: worked thanks man :) @primusa